# Android How to dependency inject variables into non activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-jetpack, dagger-hilt

I have an android application and I would like to perform dependency injection on a class which is not activity or fragment therefore the applicationContext is not present.

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App: Application {
  @Inject
  lateinit var analytics: Analytics
  
  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    // other details  
  }

}
```

My AppModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
abstract class AppModule() {
  
  companion object {
    @Provide
    @Singleton
    fun provideSomeClass(): SomeClass = SomeClass()
  }
}
```

If I try to inject **SomeClass** in a activity it works fine but not on a non activity class it fails with an error **Object is not initialized**.

```
class Consumer {

   @lateinit var SomeClass someClass;
}
```

Can someone point what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you get solution without constructor ?

Answer (score 1):

## Inject a field of a non-Activity class

To do this you have to create an `Interface` that will be an `@EntryPoint`,
and pass to that interface the `ApplicationContext`.

### Code sample:

```kotlin
// No annotations here
class Consumer(ctx: Context) { // pass here the Android context

   // Create an Interface (required by @InstallIn)
  @EntryPoint
  @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class) // this could be implementation specific
  interface Injector {
    fun getSomeClass(): SomeClass // getter that will be injected 
    // you can also define a proper Kotlin Getter here
  }

  // create the injector object
  val injector = EntryPoints.get(ctx, Injector::class.java)
  // retrieve the injected object
  val someObject = injector.getSomeClass()

  suspend fun andFinallyUseIt() {
    someObject.someMethod()
  }
}
```

---

## More:

- Make sure you don't winde your [scope](https://dagger.dev/hilt/components.html#:%7E:text=Service-,Component%20lifetimes,-The%20lifetime%20of)
- Read more: [Dagger @EntryPoint](https://dagger.dev/hilt/entry-points)

Answer (score 0):

Use inject in constructor

```
class Consumer @Inject constructor(private val someclass:SomeClass){
   //some code
}
```

Comment: what if we don't want in constructor ?